# How to parse a Html and get the result as a String using Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup, jericho-html-parser

I want to Parse a Html and get the result as a string.
Given that the Body of the Outer Html contains another Html String, I want that inner Html as output String.

Example> Input HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head></head><body><p>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br />&lt;html&gt;<br />&lt;body&gt;<br /><br />&lt;h1&gt;My First Heading&lt;/h1&gt;<br /><br />&lt;p&gt;My first paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;<br /><br />&lt;/body&gt;<br />&lt;/html&gt;<br /><br /></p></body></html>
```

Output String :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
```

Important : I am using a HTML editor in which if I input something, it returns the HTML represantation for that Input on doing getText, the first Html String above is that representation only.

Also the output string should be same as when I run the first String here(http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic)

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with some regexp :

```
(<!DOCTYPE html>).*(<html>.*</html>).+
```

And taking group 1 and group 2,

```
    tst = tst.replaceAll("<", "<").replaceAll(">",">");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<!DOCTYPE html>).*(<html>.*</html>).*</html>.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tst);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2));
```

exemple runnning : 
http://rextester.com/JTOJ89529

Comment: I have edited my question just now.

Now If you try that first statement here(http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document)
then you will get something like the second statement.
I need something like that.

Actually I am using a HTML editor in which if I input something, it returns the HTML represantation for that Input on doing getText. I want to parse it and get the original content.

Comment: Just replace char before applying regex : tst = tst.replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&gt;",">"); I've edited the response and example running according.